# Reading a tsv file in pyspark

Tags: pyspark

I want to read a tsv file but it has no header I am creating my own schema nad then trying to read TSV file but after applyting schema it is showing all columns values as null.Below is my code and result.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField,StringType,IntegerType
schema = StructType([StructField("id_code", IntegerType()),StructField("description", StringType())])
df=spark.read.csv("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/`connection_type`.tsv",schema=schema)
df.show();
+-------+-----------+
|id_code|description|
+-------+-----------+
|   null|       null|
|   null|       null|
|   null|       null|
|   null|       null|
|   null|       null|
+-------+-----------+
```

If i read it simply without applying any schema.

```
df=spark.read.csv("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/connection_type.tsv",sep="/t")
df.show()
+-----------------+
|              _c0|
+-----------------+
| 0 Not Specified |
| 1 Modem         |
| 2 LAN/Wifi      |
| 3 Unknown       |
| 4 Mobile Carrier|
+-----------------+
```

It is not coming in a proper way. Can anyone please help me with this. My sample file is .tsv file and it has below records.

```
0   Specified
1   Modemwifi
2   LAN/Wifi
3   Unknown
4   Mobile user
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the `sep` option and if it is really tab-separated, this will work.

```
df = spark.read.option("inferSchema","true").option("sep","\t").csv("test.tsv").show()

+---+-----------+
|_c0|        _c1|
+---+-----------+
|  0|  Specified|
|  1|  Modemwifi|
|  2|   LAN/Wifi|
|  3|    Unknown|
|  4|Mobile user|
+---+-----------+
```